# Angular 8: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, authentication, http-post

I'm developing a demo authentication module as I'm still learning Angular. The auth page includes a form for authentication and once the user clicks "login" it triggers a post request and validate the message on the response to check if it's a success or error message.
The problem is when I start the project using ng serve I get this error

```
 ERROR in src/app/auth-req.service.ts(26,38): error TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/auth-req.service.ts(27,20): error TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Here's the code in auth-req-service.ts file

```
constructor(private authS: AuthReqService, private generalS: GeneralSService, private route: Router) {}

login(userData: {email: string, password: string}) {
  this.http.post('http://localhost/apiapp/login.php', userData).pipe(catchError(
  (errorRes) => {
  console.log(errorRes.url);
  console.log(errorRes.name);
  console.log(errorRes.message);
  return throwError(errorRes);
}
)).subscribe( (response) => {
  this.responseMsg.next(response.message);
  if (response.message === 'Logged in') {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', '1');
    this.generalS.isAuthenticated.next(true);
  } else {
    this.generalS.isAuthenticated.next(false);
  }
}, error => {
  // alert(error.message);
} );
}
```

I call this function after clicking the login button

```
submitForm(form: NgForm) {
  let email: string = form.value.email;
  let  password: string = form.value.password;
  let userData = {email, password};
  this.authS.login(userData);
```

So why does it check the "response.message" at the beginning and not waiting for the click listener. it's pretty sure there's no response before clocking the button so there will be no message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you use a generic `post` method without generic parameter. To fix this, you should do this:

```js
this.http.post<any>(....)   // instead of "any" you can use concrete type of "response" that you expect
```

This way the `response` won't be of type `Object` but of type `any` (or your *concrete* type if you use that type instead of `any`). For future reference, since you are using new `HttpClientModule` (the one since *Angular 4.3*) you should always use http methods (*POST*, *GET*,...) with generic parameters.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmb5nz) is the stackblitz example demonstrating this.

Hope this helps.